# Does TextMate have an untabify function?

Tags: textmate

In Emacs you can use the untabify function to convert all the tabs into white spaces. Does TextMate have something similar? Any keyboard shortcuts?

Note: I have tried to use soft tab but that is not what I want. I really want to remove all the tab chars and use white spaces instead.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it does: `Text -> Convert -> Tabs to Spaces`. There is no keyboard shortcut for this by default.

Comment: This is no longer true.

Answer (score 1):

This has moved to the "Source" bundle.  Its shortcut is <kbd>Command Control Shift T</kbd>, which is the same shortcut for converting spaces to tabs.